# I'm at an awesome job, but an even better one made me an offer

Tags: job-search, career-development, job-security

A little backstory, I work in a marketing tech role that's pretty rare. It's an underdeveloped but very quickly growing field. I spent about 8 months at my last role before getting an offer to move to Manhattan and work for one of the top companies in the world in the discipline. The pay is not bad, but the real benefit is getting knowledge in a super niche area that all companies are interested in. This company promotes rarely and doesn't give pay increases often. Even the top people who have been there 4-5 years plus are still only senior analysts. I've been working there three months thus far.

The issue is I've just gotten an offer from another large company who is investing a quarter of a billion dollars investing in their technology department. They'd like me to be a lead in this niche space, operating as a manager and helping to build and lead the team for a MUCH  higher pay (Almost 60% higher...80% including bonuses). This company is stable and not a start up and I'll have command over my specific niche plus other niches I already have experience in. I'd jump to a management role that would have taken 4+ years where I am now.

I've already gotten an offer letter and they want me to start asap. I wanted to get some other professional opinions. Would it be better to take a bit of a risk and jump ship for potentially much greater rewards, pay, and management or stay where I am for the sake of a learning opportunity?

Comment: From what I am reading, take it.

Comment: We can't decide what's best for you - but it sounds like you're getting everything you want from the new job, with the ability to keep learning. I can't see why you're even considering not taking it.

Comment: Why do you have an offer letter if you weren't interested in leaving?  It's not as if these things spring out of nowhere.  So it seems to me you have already made your mind up and just want reassurance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the pros and cons of both jobs to make a decision.  This is what I see from your post:

Current Job

- Pros

  1. Top Company in the field you work in
  2. Great opportunity to learn
  3. You know what you are in for
- Cons

  1. Little chance of promotion
  2. Small/infrequent raises

New Job

- Pros

  1. Established company
  2. Opportunity to lead
  3. Significant pay increase
- Cons

  1. Possibly increased work-load
  2. You would be in a management role, as opposed to a tech/development role which you may not want/be prepared for
  3. Unknown factor.  You never really know what the work environment is going to be like until you work there.

You will need to come up with your own pros and cons, but from what I see, I would have to have *serious* misgivings about the company itself and/or my ability/desire to take on the new role to turn down that kind of promotion and pay increase.